# Use Velocity macros to render page content dynamically

Tags: macros, velocity

I am new to Velocity. I have a requirement as follows.

I have a dropdown in jsp page with the following values.

1 Normal
2 Reverse

If I select 1, then the properties for Normal Auction should be displayed on the same page
If I select 2, then the properties for Reverse Auction should be displayed on the same page

Can anyone guide me how to use velocity macros to achive the same?

A small piece of sample code can really help.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a job for javascript.

Comment: Definitely sounds like you want client side DOM manipulation (javascript), not server side text rendering (Velocity).

Answer (score 0):

Velocity macros cannot be called from a webpage, which is what I believe you want to do. You could achieve what you are asking by reloading the page and therefore rendering the Velocity template but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Basically it doesn't seem that velocity is the right solution for you and as serg and Nathan have said, using Javascript to manipulate CSS or DOM will probably be the best solution. Check out DHTML on w3schools to learn how to do this http://www.w3schools.com/dhtml/